# unexpected token error in the code

Tags: javascript

thr below is my code, i try to make tdsum an array, but some how error shows up and i cannot fix it no matter what i did, can anyone please help me, i have tried to replace ntr with numbers and other characters, but it does not work either, so i suspect that there is something i missed that is not related to the ntr part

```
var tdsum = [];
function find(element,ntr) {
  alert(element.cells[0].innerHTML);
  var tr_sum = element.parentNode.childElementCount
  var tdsum[ntr] = element.childElementCount;
  alert(ntr);
  alert(tdsum[2])
}
$('#row2').click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't declare elements in an array. You only need to declare the array itself.

Remove the `var` on this line:

```
tdsum[ntr] = element.childElementCount;
```

Comment: @EnRicoLam Great! Don't forget to mark this as the answer.